# Editing JSON data in React app

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

React newbie here.

I've created an app that parses JSON data and creates `<input>` elements by traversing through the JSON. I'm wondering how should I "tag" the `<input>` elements so that I could easily post the data to server (and transform back to JSON). Perhaps I should provide a `ref` for each element but how should I name them? Is there any "shortcut" for this kind of problem?

Here's an example JSON data:

```
{
  "persons": {
    "me": {
      name: "John Smith",
      phone: "123-456-789",
      address: {
        "1": {
          street: "123 Some Street",
          city: "City McCityface"
        },
        "2": {
          street: "456 Some Other Street",
          city: "Town McTownface"
        }
      }
    },
    "you": {
      name: "John Doe",
      phone: "999-888-777",
      address: {
        "1": {
          street: "999 Some Road",
          city: "Village McVillageface"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "settings": {
    foo: "bar",
    count: 50,
    something: "else"
  }
}
```

TL;DR: What's the smartest way edit the above data in a React app?

Comment: Do you want an JSON editor?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOmeWv?editors=001

Comment: create sub-component that render the <input> element with a function that update model by onChange or onBlur

Comment: @JanakaDissanayake: That's probably something I'm looking for. Any hints on implementing the function?

Comment: http://appliedmathematicsanu.github.io/plexus-form/

Comment: https://react.rocks/example/react-jsonschema-form